# Large title UINavigationbar bottom line flickers on scroll

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller with a tableview in it. Pulling down on the tableview expands the navigationbar as expected but the bottom hair line flickers. Has anyone faced this problem before?

[image: ?]

Comment: I guess this is happening due to, u are testing it in simulator, and the screen monitor is different.. are you facing same in real device ??

Comment: I recorded this on an actual device.

Comment: I've unable to reproduce the issue. it is working fine for me so can you please provide any sample project with the same issue?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this in a playground? Might someone answer this question if you are able to provide that example

Comment: @JonSetting I must agree with Shoaib, You should post a sample code which proves this behaviour, some seem actually try to reproduce your problem which I find quite unfair! wasting other's time.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest possible solution will be simply set self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clear & add a label(identical to seprator line)inside your tableview cell or header.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using storyboard and have a embedded UINavigationController then just un-check **Translucent** property from attribute inspector.[image]

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

Comment: This works! It brings up a new issue though, when doing the transition. With this one, you will get a black background during the transition from main to detail view, if the detail view isn't with large titles. This is due to the navigationcontroller's view's background. Simply change this with `navigationController.view.backgroundColor = .white` and you're good to go :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Please check that your `UITableView`'s content (cells, header) are clipped to bounds.
2. The issue may be with shadows, if you use them. (Can not tell for sure)

Comment: Clipping to bounds did not help and I am not using any shadows.

Answer (score 1):

Find the source of the dark gray color and change it to UIColor.clear

I would guess it's the background color of the top UIView and as it expands and contracts its size, there's a 0.5px delay every few pixels.

*It's hard to tell without seeing your code.*

Comment: it seems to be navigationBar tintColor:

removing navigationBar.barTintColor custom color, fix in my app (pay attention, do not set barTintColor to .clear, don't custom tintColor)

Answer (score 1):

removing navigationBar.barTintColor custom color, fix in my app
(pay attention, do not set barTintColor to .clear, don't custom tintColor)

Answer (score -1):

Try Insert "self.view.layoutSubviews()" in your tableView code.