# UINavigationController Border disappears when using Large Title

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder, uinavigationbar

I wanted to update my app to look more like the other native iOS11 or iOS12 apps - where the `UINavigationBar`s are using the *"Large Title"*. In Interface Builder I simply select the `UINavigationController` and set the "Prefers Large Title" attribute (see screenshot).

[image: "Attribute Inspector for UINavigationController"]

The navigation controller is displayed correctly in Interface Builder, with a beautiful large title and a thin border line at the bottom of the bar.

[image: Border at the bottom of UINavigationBar]

And here is my problem. When running the app on my iPhone XS to test it on a real device, the thin border line disappears when the navigation bar shows the "Large Title". When scrolling down - so that the title becomes smaller - the border is showing up. I tried everything, but nothing solved my problem.

[image: Screenshot from my iPhone XS]
[image: Screenshot from my iPhone XS]

And this is really annoying, because when scrolling the border line seems to be there, because it starts "flickering" a litte bit. But when I stop to scroll, the line isn't visible.

Comment: Look into this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49439555/large-title-uinavigationbar-bottom-line-flickers-on-scroll